# cannot find symbol variable ToolbarMain

Tags: android

I'm creating a sample recyclerview in Android Studio, but when I build the app I got some problem:

1. cannot find symbol variable ToolbarMain(MainActivity.java:31)
2. cannot find the symbol variable lvMain(MainActivity.java:32)

Can anyone help me? Here is the code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/ToolbarMain">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lvMain"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ToolbarMain"
        android:divider="@null">


    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.azripra.mytestingapplications;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setupUIViews();
        initToolbar();
    }

    private void setupUIViews() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.ToolbarMain);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Timetable App");
    }

    private void setupListView(){

        String[] title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Main);
        String[] description = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Description);

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, title, description);
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

    }

    public class SimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private Context mContext;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private TextView title, description;
        private String[] titleArray, descriptionArray;
        private ImageView imageView;

        public SimpleAdapter(Context context, String[] title, String[] description){
            mContext = context;
            titleArray = title;
            descriptionArray = description;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return titleArray.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return titleArray[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity_single_item, null);
            }

            title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMain);
            description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivMain);

            title.setText(titleArray[position]);
            description.setText(descriptionArray[position]);

            if(titleArray[position].equalsIgnoreCase("Timetable")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_table);
            }else if (titleArray[position].equalsIgnoreCase("Subjects")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_book);
            }else if (titleArray[position].equalsIgnoreCase("Faculty")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_contact);
            }else{
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_settings);
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }

}
```

main_activity_single_item.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivMain"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvMain"
            android:text="Timetable"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivMain"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
            android:text="Description"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvMain"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivMain"
            android:textSize="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvClick"
            android:text="Click Here"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvDescription"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivMain"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

build.gradle(:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.azripra.mytestingapplications"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

}
```

**Thank You very much for helping :)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

You know, in this void:

```
private void setupUIViews() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.ToolbarMain);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
}
```

you have no access to your `activity_main.xml` so there are two ways for you:
1.

```
private void setupUIViews() {
View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main , null);
toolbar = (Toolbar)mView.findViewById(R.id.ToolbarMain);
listView = (ListView)mView.findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
```

}

2.
take your code out from `private void setupUIViews(){}`and paste it in your `onCreate()` without any change.